# Playing a game on a "complete" Carcassonne board

Tags: carcassonne

Imagine you have just finished playing Carcassonne - you have an interesting, pseudo-randomly generated map. Are there any (published) games that you can play on that map?

Or are there any other pairs of games that you can play so that the first game is the setup for the second?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. Though I agree with you that this is very interesting, the SE format is not very suited for open questions like this one. Furthermore, this would appear to be a 'game recommendations' question, which is off topic for B&CGSE.

Comment: @freekvd - My initial thought is that this question was not on topic, but reading through the "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" (http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page I didn't see anything about recommendations.

Comment: try this list (http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead. "Game Recommendation/Shopping questions" are listed there, hidden near the bottom of the page. I agree it's not easy to find.

Comment: Is this really a recommendation question?? OP is asking if he can play a game with the board that he just finished made. maybe a game (a fan game?) has an input on a carcassonne finished board....

Comment: @gbianchi It is absolutely a game recommendation question: which games can I play under a specific set of restraints (in this case a randomized Carcassonne board). There is no best possible answer to that question, only more popular and less popular answers.

Comment: @freekvd But he's not asking for which games can *he* play. He's asking which games *exist*. It's not like "my wife doesn't like games with four letter names".

Comment: @corsiKa so we can at least narrow it down to existing games that can be played on a random map. Like D&D, or games that revolve around claiming territories (there's at least 2 I could think of that would work just fine), or anything from this (non-exhaustive) list of miniatures games https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Miniatures_games

Comment: @Jonny Unfotrunately this question is now locked. But nevertheless you might have a look on the game [Alaska](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1387/alaska) from 1979. This game is built on two more or less equal halves. Where as during th first half the players build up the playing field (freezing floes), which is afterwards broken down (melting ice) in the second half.